# I want to draw big network graph with python networkx

Tags: python-2.7, networkx, bigdata

I have network with text file.
This is network file format.
**(source,target,weight)
(2,167480,2)
(2,257789,1)
(2,1838,1)**

The network file have 403915 nodes(source).

This is my code

```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = open("C:\\Users\\UrbanLab-4\\Desktop\\exercise\\remake3.txt",'r')
f_1 = f.read().split()
i = []
G = nx.Graph()
for lineF in f_1:
    i = lineF.split(',',2)
    G.add_nodes_from(i)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos, cmap=plt, node_color = 'values')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,arrows=True)
plt.show()
```

Then I have this error..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/UrbanLab-4/PycharmProjects/untitled/net.py", line 12, in <module>
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\layout.py", line 287, in fruchterman_reingold_layout
    A = nx.to_numpy_matrix(G, weight=weight)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\convert_matrix.py", line 369, in to_numpy_matrix
    M = np.zeros((nlen,nlen), dtype=dtype, order=order) + np.nan
MemoryError
```

How solve this problem?

Comment: how many edges?

Comment: Um...very many edges. about 10000000 edges..... Surely this many edges   effect Memory error??

Comment: Yeah, you are creating an array with (4*10^5)^2 entries; each entry is a float, probably 64 bit, which yields a 10 TB large array, give or take, that you are trying to create in memory. Even if you somehow find a way around this problem, I think that you will have trouble plotting this many nodes and connections. Depending on the matplotlib backend, you will probably exceed the maximum number of plot elements.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to show with this plot?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I want to show graph and analysis this graph. This is a homework. Then I delete some node??

Comment: I would check that you're actually expected to use the spring layout.  If it's an "urban network" (as the directory suggests), it's likely that there is some implicit spatial location for these nodes.  Plotting of very large networks usually just looks like a ball of hair.

Comment: Currently I do not have coordinates, but I can get it. But what is it related to?